# Chart sheets not accessible using Apps script in Spreadsheet

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had created a spreadsheet, add data to it, prepare a chart and move the chart to their own sheet (this will create second sheet).

write an apps script and assign it to image button to go direct to chart sheet:

```js
function goToSheet3() {
  goToSheet("Chart2");
}

function goToSheet(sheetName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

But it is not working like below:

[image]

[image]

Is there any other way to do this, in which I can access charts sheet as same as other sheets.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do and the information provided does not seem sufficient. From what I understand you're trying to create a chart from the info on one sheet and then move that chart to another sheet? Are you moving/copying the data as well? Because without the data to bind to, the chart on the second sheet will not appear unless it's accessing data from the first sheet. However, all the relative code to this process will be required to figure out what exactly might be going wrong and where.